# "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build an image from a specific Dockerfile, and tag it at the same time; I am following the [online instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#tag-an-image--t) for`docker build`, but I get the following error:

> "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s)

#### My directory structure:

```
project/
    foo/
    MyDockerfile
```

This is the command I run:

`docker build -f /full/path/to/MyDockerfile -t proj:myapp`

I have tried various combinations of the above command, but the results are always the error message given above. Why is this happening - as I am following what the documentation says?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Parameter `-f` changes the name of the Dockerfile (when it's different than regular `Dockerfile`). It is not for passing the full path to `docker build`. The path goes as the first argument.

Syntax is:

`docker build [PARAMS] PATH`

So in your case, this should work:

`docker build -f MyDockerfile -t proj:myapp /full/path/to/`

or in case you are in the project directory, you just need to use **a dot**:

`docker build -f MyDockerfile -t proj:myapp .`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation (+1), strangely enough, I didn't understand it that way when I read the docs - it is a rather unusual way of passing args to a command ...

Comment: If you do "docker build --help" and read "-f" option it says the following : 
"-f, --file string             Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')"
PATH is mentioned.

Comment: I forgot the dot at the end. Thanks alot for the extra effort to pinpoint that!

Comment: Sooooo, somebody really went out of their way to make this convoluted and over-complicated. What about just letting us use -f to specify file AND path together? ;-)

Comment: Yes, I also thought that while the default is `PATH/Dockerfile` giving `-f` would override that completely.

Answer (score 91):

> **docker build .**

### DO NOT MISS "THE DOT".

Answer (score 12):

A.  Please upvote Krzysztof's answer.  I was lost without his hints.

But B, my contribution.

I was able to use a full path for the --file argument.

```
docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE="/source/java/mystuff/build/libs/mything-1.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar" --file /full/path/to/MyDockerfile -t proj:myapp .
```

I had forgotten that little "." at the end.

D'oh!

Aka, do NOT overlook the last little "." (period) at the end !!!

Answer (score 8):

**sudo docker build -t my-app .**

Don't forget to add **DOT** at the end.

reference: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/

Answer (score 1):

You can also receive this error if there are spaces in your build arguments.  For example:

```
--build-arg AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY = $(agent.builddirectory)
```

generated the
`"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.` errors message, and removing the spaces around the equals sign

```
--build-arg AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY=$(agent.builddirectory)
```

works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're converting your build from a shell script to i.e. gitlab-ci, you might encounter this problem due to different multiline syntaxes:

I.e shell script may have:

```
 docker build . -t the-something \
  --build-arg COMMIT_SHA=${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
```

wherease gitlab ci dont need the trailing backslash for multiline:

```
 script:
- docker build . the-something
  --build-arg COMMIT_SHA=${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
```

If you keep the trailing backslash, it will be part of the command line and considered an argument.