# Docker build requires exactly 1 argument

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

When I run this command on my gitlab pipeline

```
docker build --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN} --tag $REGISTRY_IMAGE/web-public:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $REGISTRY_IMAGE/web-public:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME packages/web-public
```

it fails with

> build requires exactly 1 argument

It looks to me like I am actually passing one argument, the path; `packages/web-public`. Flags are not arguments as far as I know.

What am I missing here?

This is the structure of my project

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quote your variables. Something in those variables is expanding to be more than the single arg to the flag.

```
docker build --build-arg "NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN}" --tag "$REGISTRY_IMAGE/web-public:$CI_COMMIT_SHA" --tag "$REGISTRY_IMAGE/web-public:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" packages/web-public
```

You can also echo that command to see how the variables are expanding, e.g.

```
echo docker build ...
```

Answer (score 4):

from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

```
docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
```

It looks like there's something wrong with your `PATH`. Try using the absolute path or change to the directory containing the `Dockerfile` and use `.`

see also: ["docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517241/docker-build-requires-exactly-1-arguments/46517290)

Comment: That does not seem to be the issue. Look at the question, I have updated it.
I had already read both links you have referenced, btw

Comment: Then it's your variable expansion as mentioned in the answer of bmitch

Answer (score 3):

My issue was that I had a multi line script entry, eg

```
script:
    - >
      docker build \
      --network host \
      -t ${CI_REGISTRY}/kylehqcom/project/image:latest \
      ....
```

As soon as I added to a single line, we were all ok. So I guess the line breaks got "entered" after the first line which meant that the subsequent lines were ignored and the error was returned. Also note, that I CI linted via the GitLab ui and all was syntactically correct.