# docker: specifying a Dockerfile - "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument

Tags: docker

The docs say:

```
docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
```

and

```
--file , -f     Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')
```

so I'm using

```
docker build -t <my tag> -f /path/to/my/Dockerfile>
```

but I get:

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
```

How do the docs need correcting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517241/docker-build-requires-exactly-1-arguments)

Comment: You forgot path I think. Add `.` after `build`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `-f` doesn't set the path to the Dockerfile, but the name of the file used as a Dockerfile. you would need to do something like

```sh
docker build -t <tag> <path to the folder of the Dockerfile named X> -f X
```

More details, as mentioned, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517241/docker-build-requires-exactly-1-arguments).